# Combining Multiple Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions

I have two functions that have been modelled with the Fourier Series $f(x)=-x^2$ and $g(x)=-x$, both functions period of $2pi$.

The fourier series of $-x^2$ is given by $5.75+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2\sin(n\pi)-n\pi\cos(n\pi)}{n^2}(\cos(nx))$

The fourier series of $-x$ is given by $3.63+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^n}{n}(\sin(nx)$

Is there a way to combine these two Fourier Series to produce a new periodic function somewhat resembling this?
([Example of new periodic function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpgCU.png))

(Sorry I can't insert image directly as I don't have requisite points)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to combine these two formulae short of computing the Fourier coefficients "from the drawing board".  It still requires a certain amount of tedious algebra, and for that reason I will only provide a sketch of the solution.

First, let me generalize the situation a little.  Call the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$, let $a,b$ be $2\pi$-periodic functions on $\mathbb{C}$, and define $$K(b,a)(x)=\begin{cases}b(2x)&x\leq0\\a(2x)&x>0\end{cases}$$ and $$(Tf)(x)=f(-x)$$  Then \begin{gather*}
K(b,a)=K(b,0)+K(0,a) \\
TK(b,0)=K(0,Tb)
\end{gather*}  Since the Fourier transform is linear and (by abuse of notation) $\mathcal{F}T=T\mathcal{F}$, it suffices to compute $\mathcal{F}K(0,a)$.

Second, suppose $\omega$ is even.  Then \begin{align*}
(\mathcal{F}K(0,a))(\omega)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi{e^{\omega xi}K(0,a)\,dx} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi{e^{\omega xi}a(2x)\,dx} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{\frac{\omega}{2}ui}a(u)\,du} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{F}a)\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Third, suppose $\omega$ is odd.  Then \begin{align*}
(\mathcal{F}K(0,a))(\omega)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{\frac{\omega}{2}ui}a(u)\,du} \\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{\frac{\omega}{2}ui}\sum_{\kappa\in\mathbb{Z}}{(\mathcal{F}a)(\kappa)e^{-\kappa ui}}\,du} \\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\sum_{\kappa\in\mathbb{Z}}{(\mathcal{F}a)(\kappa)\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{\left(\frac{\omega}{2}-\kappa\right)ui}}\,du} \\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\sum_{\kappa\in\mathbb{Z}}{(\mathcal{F}a)(\kappa)\frac{2i}{\frac{\omega}{2}-\kappa}\,du}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you that's extremely helpful